# Edit contents of front-end HTML file based on value from express-session

Tags: javascript, express, web-applications, express-session

I am currently trying to build a login page for my web application using express-session. I have everything working as far as confirming a valid login.

Once a valid login is confirmed, I run the following code within the app.post() method.

```
request.session.loggedIn = true
request.session.username = data[0].account_user
response.redirect('/')
```

The redirect takes me back to the home page. How can I then now check the value of those variables, and edit what the user sees on the front-end?

For example if nobody is logged in, I want it to display login/signup buttons. If they are logged in, I want to hide those and display their username.

Comment: How are you rendering your front-end files? Do you use EJS or some template engine?

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest setting your req.session vars in your login route directly as opposed to attaching it via app.post().

After successful login, you can then respond with a `res.status(200).json([the data you want to send])`.  On the frontend, check to see if the the result is ok or for a specific status code - based on that you can set a localStorage var and/or redirect the user to the homepage using location.href("/").